# Machine Learning: Does computing the accuracy score for binary labels always result in a low accuracy score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

If I have 2 labels (1 and 0), and after I pass my logits through a softmax activation layer, I get something like:

```
[[0.1, 0.9],
[0.3, 0.7],
[0.333, 0.667]]
```

as a predictions output, and my labels are only 1 or 0, does this always result in a low accuracy? Meaning to say if I have a lot more classes,  will my softmax layer give me something close to either 1 or 0 for each of the classes, which give me a higher accuracy score?

Further, if I want to use accuracy as my metric, is there a way to scale my probability to either 0 or 1? Can be this be done by applying a mask in TensorFlow that outputs boolean values whenever a probability hits 0.5 or above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After softmax layer you have probabilities in range 0..1, 
so if you want to check accuracy against your labels being only 0 or 1 you have to convert probablities

if pred>0.5 then pred=1
if pred<=0.5 then pred=0